# powershell website automatic deployment

Tags: iis, octopus-deploy

We are using TeamCity for builds and Octopus for deployment. Octopus uses Deploy.ps1 powershell script for MVC website deployment to IIS.

I am looking for a powershell that can

1. check if website exists and if not create one
2. check if appPool exists and if not create one
3. check if webapplication exists and if not create one with appPool from step2.

Any useful links that show how this deployment can be automated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this information might be useful for you.

> The IIS Website and Application Pool feature in Octopus allows for a large number of options to be configured during deployment.

..

> **Web Site**
>   If enabled, Tentacle will use use the PowerShell Web Administration module to attempt to create or modify an IIS Web Site and Application Pool using the settings below.

http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/IIS+Websites+and+Application+Pools